# Can you locally store tweets from twitter API

Tags: php, mysql, twitter

Are you allowed to locally store tweets obtained using the twitter api?
http://apiwiki.twitter.com/Twitter-Search-API-Method%3A-search

Comment: "Allowed to"? Is this a programming question, or a policy question?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the [Twitter TOS](http://twitter.com/tos):

> By submitting, posting or displaying
>   Content on or through the Services,
>   you grant us a worldwide,
>   non-exclusive, royalty-free license
>   (with the right to sublicense) to use,
>   copy, reproduce, process, adapt,
>   modify, publish, transmit, display and
>   distribute such Content in any and all
>   media or distribution methods (now
>   known or later developed).
>
> [TIP] **This license is you authorizing
>   us to make your Tweets available to
>   the rest of the world and to let
>   others do the same.** But what’s yours
>   is yours – you own your content.

In other words, yes, you can store them, and reproduce them at will. That page also links to 
 the [API rules](http://twitter.com/apirules), which have a few requirements, like attributing tweets, not editing them to change their meaning, and getting permission before using them commercially (like on t-shirts).

Answer (score 5):

Yes. You're encouraged to cache tweets to avoid being rate-limited; see http://apiwiki.twitter.com/FAQ for more.